# HTTP 500 Internal Server Error - Azure Bot Serivice

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, azure-appservice

I have developed a bot on node.js as a teams app using the yo teams generator. The bot is hosted and deployed on an azure app service web app. The bot was working fine all the while, but started throwing http 500 internal server errors in the past couple of weeks.

I am not sure what has changed, but I am trying to fix this issue but not finding any leads and useful information from appInsights or the trace logs. All I see is the below exception being thrown in appInsights:
"POST to the bot's endpoint failed with HTTP status 500"

The bot works perfectly fine locally, when debugging through ngrok. Please let me know how I can fix this or where I can look for useful logs to help resolve this.

Comment: Refer how to [set up Application Insights for your ASP.NET website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net). The Bot Framework (starting with v4.2) provides an additional level of Application Insights telemetry, but it is not required for diagnosing HTTP 500 errors.

Comment: I was able to resolve this with MS on a support ticket. Looks like the fix is to update the configuration setting to reflect the latest version of node from 12.13 to 16.13.0 in the app service config section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this with MS on a support ticket. Looks like the fix is to update the configuration setting to reflect the latest version of node from 12.13 to 16.13.0 in the app service config section.